# what value of the pressure will a aluminum rod fit inside the steel ring? (Bulk modulus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, statics

A rod of aluminum has a diameter of 1.000002 cm. A ring of cast steel has an inner diameter of 1.000000 cm. If the rod and the ring are placed in a
liquid under high pressure, at what value of the pressure will the aluminum
rod fit inside the steel ring?

I was trying:

$$\frac{F}{A} = \frac{\Delta V * B }{V}$$

however the volume is:

$$V = \pi r^2 * h$$

and I dont have the height so I got stuck does any one have an idea?, I was trying to take the height as 1 but didnt work

note:bulk modulus for aluminium and steel is:

$$B_a = 7.5*10^{10}$$
$$B_s = 17*10^{10}$$

update: @goncalo told me aluminuim is isotropic so:

$$\frac{\Delta r}{r} = \frac{\Delta V}{3V}$$

I was trying:

$$3\frac{\Delta r}{r}B = 449999$$

but this is wrong the correct answer is: 810000pa

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145769/discussion-on-question-by-pulsar-plasma-what-value-of-the-pressure-will-a-alumin); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_a$ be the radius of the rod of aluminum.

Also, let $r_s$ be the inner radius of the steel ring.

Then, we have
$$\frac{B_a(r_a−r)}{r_a}=\frac{B_s(r_s−r)}{r_s}$$
Solving this for $r$, we get
$$r=\frac{B_s-B_a}{\frac{B_s}{r_s}-\frac{B_a}{r_a}}$$

Therefore, we see that $\frac{3B_a}{r_a}(r_a-r)$ can be written as
$$\begin{align}\frac{3B_a}{r_a}(r_a-r)&=\frac{3B_a}{r_a}\bigg(r_a-\frac{B_s-B_a}{\frac{B_s}{r_s}-\frac{B_a}{r_a}}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{3B_a}{r_a}\bigg(r_a-\frac{(B_s-B_a)r_sr_a}{B_sr_a-B_ar_s}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{3B_a}{r_a}\bigg(\frac{r_a(B_sr_a-B_ar_s)-(B_s-B_a)r_sr_a}{B_sr_a-B_ar_s}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{3B_a}{r_a}\bigg(\frac{B_sr_a(r_a-r_s)}{B_sr_a-B_ar_s}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{3B_aB_s(r_a-r_s)}{B_sr_a-B_ar_s}\end{align}$$
from which you will get the answer.